# File upload too large

Tags: coldfusion

I use cffile action="Upload", and it works just fine for smaller files.
But yesterday, I tried uploading a 42Meg pdf and it just sat there all night long.

Q: Is there something I should know regarding uploading larger files?  I define larger as: the one that sat there all night long and never timed out and never uploaded.  For instance, is there a cflib or Riaforge routine that was written to handle larger files?

Right now I'm at version 8 at hosting.com.

Comment: Thanks Amardeep.  I appreciate you catching that typo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to the file upload limits in CF, most web servers (Apache, IIS, etc) have an upload limit.  Check that as well.

Comment: My host has a 50 second timeout.

Comment: Nice how-to here, first comment: http://www.webtrenches.com/post.cfm/iis7-file-upload-size-limits

Answer (score 5):

You can change setting in CFadministrator > settings > Request Size Limits

Answer (score 4):

Check the maximum post size set in ColdFusion Administrator. If it is set lower than 48 MB then you would have issues. I have uploaded much larger (200+ MB) with standard cffile with no issues.